# How to make dependency in dropdowns which is made with buttons and list

Tags: javascript, html

I have task to create dependency of options selected in first dropdown to "filter" options in second dropdown.
For this I've already create "value" in *li* tag which is acquired from the backend side. FE side is created of buttons and *ul*, *il* tags due to some css options etc.

Logic of selection is:

when I choose in first dropdown `option1` in the second dropdown should appear only `v1.0`, when `option2` is selected there should be `latest` and `v2.0` etc.

I would like to have code as much easy as possible.

This is my existing HTML page:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="name1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-hdd"></i> Choose <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li value="1"><a rel="name1">option1</a></li>
    <li value="2"><a rel="name1">option2</a></li>
    <li value="3"><a rel="name1">option3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="tag" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-hdd"></i> Choose Tag <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li value="2"><a rel="tag">latest</a></li>
    <li value="2"><a rel="tag">v2.0</a></li>
    <li value="1"><a rel="tag">v1.0</a></li>
    ... // more options ...
</ul>
</div>
```

I've started the JS with:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a[rel=name1]').on('click',function() {
    var value = $(this).parents('li').val()
```

With this I'm able to get the value from items in first dropdown but I'm lost how to continue and filter options in the second dropdown. Thank you for any help!

Comment: .val() is for form fields. Instead use data-attributes

Comment: How do you want the filtering to work?  Are we matching values from the first menu to the second?  In other words, does selecting option1 from the first only show v1.0 in the second?  Likewise, selecting option2 from the first would only show v2.0 and latest in the second while selecting option3 from the first only show nothing in the second?  Um... sorry if this question is a bit wordy  :/

Comment: yes exactly I will edit and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a `href` on the `a` it is useless - you do not even get a little hand.

Also .val() is reserved for form field which are the only object that can have a value and be valid

Instead use data-attr on the LI itself and give each ul a class

```js
$('#firstSel>li').on('click',function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $("#secondSel").find("li").hide()
    $("#secondSel").find("li[data-value="+value+"]").show();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu>li { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="name1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-hdd"></i> Choose <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="firstSel">
    <li data-value="1">option1</li>
    <li data-value="2">option2</li>
    <li data-value="3">option3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="tag" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-hdd"></i> Choose Tag <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="secondSel">
    <li data-value="2">latest</li>
    <li data-value="2">v2.0</li>
    <li data-value="1">v1.0</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible with this solution change cursor to "href link like"?